# Makefile wildcard looping

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this Makefile:

```
source = $(wildcard *.p4)
compiled_json := $(source:.p4=.json)

ifndef DEFAULT_PROG
DEFAULT_PROG = $(wildcard *.p4)
endif
DEFAULT_JSON = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(DEFAULT_PROG:.p4=.json)  

# Define NO_P4 to start BMv2 without a program
ifndef NO_P4
run_args += -j $(DEFAULT_JSON)
endif

# Set BMV2_SWITCH_EXE to override the BMv2 target
ifdef BMV2_SWITCH_EXE
run_args += -b $(BMV2_SWITCH_EXE)
endif

cpu_port = --cpu-port 255

all: run

run: build
       sudo python3 $(RUN_SCRIPT) -t $(TOPO) $(run_args) $(cpu_port)

stop:
       sudo mn -c

build: dirs $(compiled_json)

%.json: %.p4
        $(P4C) --p4v 16 $(P4C_ARGS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@ $<

dirs:
        mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR) $(PCAP_DIR) $(LOG_DIR)

clean: stop
       rm -f *.pcap
       rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR) $(PCAP_DIR) $(LOG_DIR)
```

My problem is in DEFAULT_PROG AND DEFAULT_JSON variable. If i have two .p4 files in DEFAULT_PROG variable will be something like that: DEFAULT_PROG == one.p4 another.p4. Then in DEFAULT_JSON i will have build_dir/one.json another.json but i want to have build_dir/one.json and build_dir/another. Could someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`patsubst` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html). For example, given this example:

```
DEFAULT_PROG=one.p4 another.p4
DEFAULT_JSON=$(patsubst %.p4,build_dir/%.p4,$(DEFAULT_PROG))

all:
    @echo $(DEFAULT_JSON)
```

The output of running `make all` is:

```
build_dir/one.p4 build_dir/another.p4
```

Comment: Or, `addprefix`: `$(addprefix build_dir/,$(DEFAULT_PROG))`.  You have to use a make function that will apply the change to each individual word in the variable.